# Select all node that has certain css-rule without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, selection

How to get all nodes that have certain CSS rule, for example if defined:

```
html {
  color: blue;
}
div.x {
  color: blue;
}
```

And I want to get all node that has `color: blue`, I want to get the `html` (`document.children[0]`) and all `div` with `class='x'` node only, not all the children that affected by that rule.

**EDIT** the final target is to remove certain css rule from a website, I've tried this script but doesn't work on Chrome:

```
var xRules = ['userSelect','webkitTouchCallout','webkitUserSelect','khtmlUserSelect','mozUserSelect','msUserSelect'];
var dS = document.styleSheets;
for(var z in dS) {
  var dsz = dS[z].cssRules;
  if(!dsz) continue;
  for(var y in dsz) {
    var dszy = dsz[y].style;
    if(!dszy) continue;
    console.log(dszy.webkitUserSelect);
    for(var x in xRules) {
      var xx = xRules[x];
      dszy.removeProperty(xx);
    }
  }
}
```

So all I could think is that I must find the element then remove the styling.

Comment: Can't you have a class called `blue` with that attribute and then assign that to your HTML so all you need to do is `document.querySelectorAll('.blue')`? Much easier.

Comment: no, because I want to manipulate other people's website using javascript

Comment: What kind of _manipulation_?

Comment: css manipulation.. I need to remove certain css rule from every element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the loaded css rules using `document.styleSheets`. Then, find the rules that are setting the specific property, in your case `style.color == "blue"`.

Then, get the `selectorText` from the rule, it will give you the selectors. It will be easy then to select the elements using `document.querySelector()` passing the obtained selectors as the parameter.

```js
var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
  var cls = classes[x];
  if(cls.style.color == "blue") {
    alert(cls.selectorText);
    
    //Gets a node list of the elements matching the selector
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(cls.selectorText);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  color: blue;
}
div.x {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now this is not possible with css. But what you may do is use jquery (javascript) to list all the elements and check if the color is blue.

```
$( "*" ).each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("color") === "blue") {
        // do some stuff with $(this)
    }
});
```

I am not sure if it will work since I do not know how jquery returns css color property.

I just noticed you want solution without jQuery so here it is:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(all[i], null).getPropertyValue("color") === "blue")
        // Do something with the element here
}
```

Comment: Solution you suggested without jQuery will only work if CSS rules set inline on `style` attribute, not where classes are used.

Comment: Thank you for notification, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).filter(function(el) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(el).color === 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
})
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) currently only works in Firefox but it can be easily replaced with something like `[].slice.call(...)`